# Why is b=(a+=1) an invalid syntax in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I write the following in python, I get a syntax error, why so?

```
a = 1
b = (a+=1)
```

I am using python version 2.7

what I get when I run it, the following:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = (a +=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    b = (a +=1)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: That is valid python syntax, you need to provide more information. Sorry for the downvotes, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike in some other languages, assignment (including augmented assignment, like `+=`) in Python is *not* an expression. This also affects things like this:

```
(a=1) > 2
```

which is legal in C, and several other languages.

The reason generally given for this is because it helps to prevent a class of bugs like this:

```
if a = 1: # instead of ==
    pass
else:
    pass
```

since assignment isn't an expression, this is a SyntaxError in Python. In the equivalent C code, it is a subtle bug where the variable will be *modified* rather than checked, the check will *always* be true (in C, like in Python, a non-zero integer is always truthy), and the else block can never fire.

You *can* still do chained assignment in Python, so this works:

```
>>> a = 1 
>>> a = b = a+1
>>> a
2
>>> b
2
```

Answer (score 4):

`a +=1` is a statement in Python and you can't assign a statement to a variable. Though it is a valid syntax in languages like C, PHP, etc but not Python.

```
b = (a+=1)
```

An equivalent version will be:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a += 1
>>> b = a
```

Comment: Does this mean that python does not evaluate the statement before it is assigned? Seems strange from a C perspective but I guess it prevents side effects from occurring.

Comment: @user1932405 `+=` does have a side affect, but unlike C nothing is returned in Python. So, even things like `while(x = 1){..}` are invalid in Python.

Comment: @user1932405 You got it the wrong way. Guido **purposefully** decided to *not* permit using statements, hence assignments, inside expression in order to avoid bugs (`while (a=something())` when you meant `while (a==something())` to make an example). It's not an "implementation detail" or something like that. *It's a design choice*.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ashwini stated, `a+=1` is an assigment, not a value. You can't assign it to `b`, or any variable. What you probably want is:

```
b = a+1
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers provided here are good, I just want to add that you can achieve what you want in a one-line expression, but written in a different manner:

```
b, a = a+1, a+1
```

Here you're doing *almost* the same thing: incrementing `a` by 1, and assigning the value of `a+1` to b - I'm telling 'almost' because here we have two summations instead of one.

Comment: You can do it with one summation - `a = b = a+1` works, and only evaluates `a+1` once.